# Outputting items from nested array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there an easier way all items from the inner array ?

```
$user = array(
     'name' => 'Joe Blogs',
     'age'  => 25,
     'validate' => 'true',
     'children' => array(
          'Jack',
          'Jill',
          'Mark')
);

echo "The user's details are: " . $user['children'][0] .' '. $user['children'][1] .' and '.   $user['children'][2];
```

Comment: Easier? "fix" them how?

Comment: To clarify, you want to output a string array as `item1, item2, item3, and item4`?  That is, comma-separated with a space, and with "and" before the last item?

Comment: Well its only 3 items not 4, just need a shorter way to display those Items in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `implode()`

```
<?php
$user = array(
    'name' => 'Joe Blogs',
    'age'  => 25,
    'validate' => 'true',
    'children' => array(
        'Jack',
        'Jill',
        'Mark')
);

echo "The user details are ".implode(',',$user['children']);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
The user details are Jack,Jill,Mark
```